# Android call stack how?

Tags: android, debugging

Hi 
how can i tell what the last line of my code was before it delves deep into the "source not available" I cannot find any use for the call stack at all if it does not tell me where it left my code.

Comment: If there's a crash, you can see it from the stack trace in the logcat (`...SomeClassYouWrote.java:##line`). If there's no crash I suppose you're debugging step by step, and there's the call stack in the debug view if you forget where you were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try and catch statements, and use `Log.e(someTag, e.toString());` in the catch portion, and it will tell you the error in DDMS's logcat. I know its not very efective, but you can surround each code and put a different tag for each one.

Comment: Ah yep thanks, i looked at that logcat before and it was all gibberish, however i have found that if i clear the log and click on the red E i get some helpful stuff :D